# Switch Toggled event fires when toggled programmatically

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
          ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
          IsGroupingEnabled = "true"
          SeparatorColor="White">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue" HeightRequest="25">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Key}"  FontAttributes="Bold"  LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding article_description}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13"  Margin="10,5,0,-6" Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding dish_name}" 
                                   FontSize="13" Margin="10,0,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LabelReserved"  Text="{Binding reserved}" IsVisible="false" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/> 
                            <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="False" Toggled="SwitchMenu_OnToggled" >
                                <Switch.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Switch" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference LabelReserved},
                                   Path=Text.Length}" Value="7">
                                        <Setter Property="IsToggled" Value="true" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Switch.Triggers>
                            </Switch>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: Model]

I have the listview above, that has a switch, I have a trigger to toggle the switch if the labelreserved has a legth of 7, but I dont want the Toggled event   to fire, only when the user clicks on the switch. 
Is possible to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do what you want. I would imagine that when the `IsToggled` property changes the event fires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note:*** This solution was a bit of an experiment on my part - so I would recommend that, if you decide to implement this, use it with caution.

Basically, the intent is to create a view-only solution that is able to track how the `IsToggled` property is being set - whether it is through trigger, binding context or, tap action (something similar to [property context that is maintained for `BindingContext` on `BindableObject`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs#L16))

Assuming, we have a custom-event that is triggered only when user taps the switch - this problem should be solved. Simply adding a tap-recognizer to `Switch` didn't seem to work. And we are left with 2 options:

1. Create your own custom control that provides functionality similar to  `Switch`, but only triggers the toggle event when there is a tap gesture captured - would highly recommend this option.
2. Or, you can extend existing `Switch` control with a custom event, and tracks how the `IsToggled` property is set - by providing its own set of bindable properties.

For example:

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
    internal enum ToggledSetFlags
    {
        None = 0,
        FromCode = 1 << 0,
    }

    ToggledSetFlags _toggleSetStatus = ToggledSetFlags.None;
    public event EventHandler<ToggledEventArgs> UserToggled;

    public static readonly BindableProperty ToggledStateFromCodeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "ToggledStateFromCode", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomSwitch),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            defaultValue: default(bool), propertyChanged: OnToggledStateFromCodeChanged);

    public bool ToggledStateFromCode
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ToggledStateFromCodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggledStateFromCodeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnToggledStateFromCodeChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((CustomSwitch)bindable).OnToggledStateFromCodeChangedImpl((bool)oldValue, (bool)newValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnToggledStateFromCodeChangedImpl(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
    {
        if (ToggledStateFromCode != IsToggled)
        {
            _toggleSetStatus = ToggledSetFlags.FromCode;
            IsToggled = ToggledStateFromCode;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == nameof(IsToggled))
        {
            ToggledStateFromCode = IsToggled;
            if (_toggleSetStatus == ToggledSetFlags.None)
                UserToggled?.Invoke(this, new ToggledEventArgs(IsToggled));
            else
                _toggleSetStatus = ToggledSetFlags.None;
        }
    }
}
```

And, sample usage would look like:

```
<local:CustomSwitch 
       Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" 
       ToggledStateFromCode="{Binding IsSwitchOn}" 
       UserToggled="SwitchMenu_OnToggled">
    <Switch.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomSwitch}" 
                     Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference LabelReserved},
                     Path=Text.Length}" Value="7">
            <Setter Property="ToggledStateFromCode" Value="true" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Switch.Triggers>
</local:CustomSwitch>
```

**EDIT 1:** Had missed to add `else` in `OnPropertyChanged` method while reverting custom toggled property status. Also, added check to set flag only if current toggle value is different.

**EDIT 2:** Converted bindable property to track state instead of state-less as before. This ensures the ability to handle binding changes without firing the event.

Comment: Hey, is working very well for now. I have another request, is possible to have grouped switch, in the listview above, I will have multiple switchs, but when the one switch is toggled, the others need to be untoggled.

Comment: If you have a View model - you can control that there - or does this logic have to be view level only?

Comment: Yes i have a viewmodel, how can i do in the viewmodel?
Thanks.

Comment: When the corresponding property for IsToggled is changed - set others as false using a for loop or something

Comment: When i use IsToggledFromStyle in the code to set false or true, the event fires, that isnt supposed to do, right?

Comment: `Toggled` event will always fire - `CustomToggled` event will fire only when `IsToggledFromStyle` is set.

Comment: CustomToggled event should fire, only when the switch is tapped, not when is set programmatically.

Comment: Yes - sorry for last comment - this is what I meant to write - Tapped event will always fire - but CustomTapped will only fire when user taps on cell. There is a chance it will fire if you set IsToggled through binding - so if you don't want it to fire through binding - you will have to create a bindable property for binding too like we did for togglefromstyle

Comment: Or if you are using code-behind to set IsToggledFromStyle - then the custom event shouldn't fire; but I don't think you are doing that as switch is inside a data template.

Comment: Yes i am using in the code behind to set the IsToggledFromStyle  , if a condiiton is met.
Inside the OncustomToggled event , I doing:
MySwitch sw = sender as MySwitch;

then i do sw.IsToggledFromStyle = true , and the event fires.

Comment: I am on the way - can we connect on [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221189/switch-toggled-event-fires-when-toggled-programmatically/46226416?noredirect=1#) in an hour or so?

Comment: Sorry, today I cant, maybe in 6hours, or tomorow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154550/discussion-between-phill-and-g-sharada).

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the user from toggling the switch by disabling the Switch by using the property `IsEnabled` and set it to false .

Comment: Not want i want, every time i enter in the page the toggling event fires, i just want the toggle to switch positions and no click event.

Comment: Because when the user clicks in the switch, i have to insert data in a database.

Comment: Well I would solve it like this :
1. forget about the trigger 
2. you can bind the IsToggled to a bool property in the model . 
3. the model has another bool property called "IsToggledProgramatically" 
4. You can set this property to true if the string is longer than 7 chars. 
5. when the event get fired , check the "IsToggledProgramatically" , if it is true , then ignore . 

Anyway what kind of  a solution that needs a toggle depending on it's lable text length ? :D

Comment: The kind that i dont know any better solution :D
I will see if i can implement what are you saying.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give a example, the model is in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I found a simple (somewhat incorrect) solution that I used to save a lot of extra work from the accepted answer.
When I programmatically toggle the switch, I set the Tag property to true.

```
ToggleSwitch.Tag = true;
ToggleSwitch.IsOn = true (or false);
```

Then in my Toggled event I check if the Tag property is null and perform my action. That way the only time the code is executed is when the user toggles the switch.

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = (ToggleSwitch)e.OriginalSource;
    if (toggleSwitch.Tag == null)
    {
        // Switch was toggled by user, do some action.
    }
    else
    {
        // Switch was toggled programmatically, set Tag null.
        toggleSwitch.Tag = null;
    }
}
```